# Пустая анимация unity влияет на объект

Tags: unity3d

В своей игре на unity 2d я имею объект **Gear**, у которого есть компонент **Animator**.

Я хочу сделать следующее:

1. Сначала я с помощью скрипта запущу несколько анимаций у объекта.
2. Затем я хочу, чтобы **Animator** перестал влиять на объект
3. После того как **Animator** перестанет влиять на объект, я хочу управлять **transform**ом из скрипта

Проблема:

Сначала идет несколько анимаций, которые управляют положением **Gear** на сцене. Когда включена только анимация **Empty**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она не позволяет ничему другому изменять положение объекта **Gear**, сам же объект встает в то место на сцене, где он находился на сцене до начала игры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как утроена анимация, в том плане, что пустая анимация не позволяет менять **transform**?

Попытки к решению:

1. Конечно, я могу выключить **Animator** (т. е. GetComponent().enabled = false). Но меня это не устраивает, т. к. это полностью выключит доступ к анимации
2. Я могу сделать **Gear** сыном пустого объекта в иерархии, и двигать уже пустой объект, но это, на мой взгляд, очень костыльно, и влечет за собой соответствующие проблемы.

Итак, возможно ли что-то сделать с анимацией, чтобы пустая анимации не морозила **transform**? Или это невозможно и мне нужно искать другой путь решения моей задачи?

UPD. Правильно ли я понимаю, что все переменные когда-либо упомянутые в анимации становятся недоступными к изменению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать изменять позицию `transform` в `LateUpdate()`, т.к. он вызывается после обновления анимации.

> UPD. Правильно ли я понимаю, что все переменные когда-либо упомянутые
> в анимации становятся недоступными к изменению?

Они перезаписываются значениями из анимации в специальном *Internal animation update* который идет после `Update()`. Подробнее здесь: [Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)